# Chromium won't start

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium

Something keeps happening to Chromium that times to times won't start. I already searched for other similar questions but i do not find a solution. It appears this error in the syslog everytime i try to start Chromium:

```
Nov 18 17:56:15 hiro systemd[1791]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Nov 18 17:56:15 hiro chromium_chromium.desktop[1595537]: cannot snap-exec: cannot read info for "chromium": cannot find installed snap "chromium" at revision 1399: missing file /snap/chromium/1399/meta/snap.yaml
Nov 18 17:56:15 hiro systemd[1791]: gnome-launched-chromium_chromium.desktop-1595537.scope: Succeeded.
```

But when i check for this missing file:
ls /snap/chromium/1399/meta/snap.yaml

It is there. Any ideias to fix this? Thank you.

UPDATE

I tried this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure chromium-browser
```

but did not change the problem.

Then i tried:

```
snap remove chromium
```

But return a error:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect chromium:password-manager-service from core:password-manager-service (internal error: connection "chromium:password-manager-service core:password-manager-service" not found in state)
```

the full list of errors is:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Disconnect chromium:network from core:network (cannot update mount namespace of snap "chromium": cannot update preserved namespace of snap "chromium": 
-----
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/elementary /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Yaru /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Yaru-light /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Yaru-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Yaru-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Yaru-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Radiance /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Radiance none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia-light /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia-light-compact /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia-light-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia-dark-compact /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia-dark-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Materia-compact /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Materia-compact none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-sea /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-sea none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-dark-sea /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-sea none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-dark-azul /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-azul none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-dark-aliz /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-dark-aliz none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-azul /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-azul none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Matcha-aliz /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Matcha-aliz none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Greybird /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Greybird none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Greybird-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Greybird-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme-light /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Breeze /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Breeze none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Breeze-Dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Breeze-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Arc none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc-Darker /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Arc-Darker none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc-Dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Arc-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiance /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Ambiance none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Adwaita-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/themes/Adwaita-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/sounds/communitheme /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/sounds/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/sounds/Yaru /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/sounds/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-light none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/hicolor /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/hicolor none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darker none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/communitheme /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/breeze_cursors /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/breeze_cursors none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Yaru /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Suru /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Maia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Humanity /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Humanity none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Humanity-Dark /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Humanity-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/DMZ-White /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/DMZ-White none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/DMZ-Black /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/DMZ-Black none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Breeze_Snow /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Breeze_Snow none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change unmount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1399/data-dir/icons/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Breeze_Snow /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Breeze_Snow none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/DMZ-Black /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/DMZ-Black none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/DMZ-White /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/DMZ-White none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Humanity-Dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Humanity-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Humanity /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Humanity none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Adapta-Nokto-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Dark-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Light-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Papirus-Maia /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Papirus-Maia none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Radiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Radiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Suru /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/Yaru /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/breeze_cursors /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/breeze_cursors none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/communitheme /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darker none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary-xfce /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/elementary-xfce none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/elementary /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/elementary none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/hicolor /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/hicolor none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/icons/ubuntu-mono-light none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/sounds/Yaru /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/sounds/Yaru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/sounds/communitheme /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/sounds/communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Adwaita-dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Adwaita-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Adwaita /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Adwaita none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiance /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Ambiance none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Ambiant-MATE /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Ambiant-MATE none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc-Dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Arc-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc-Darker /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Arc-Darker none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Arc /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Arc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Breeze-Dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Breeze-Dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Breeze /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Breeze none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme-dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme-light /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Communitheme-light none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Communitheme /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Communitheme none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Greybird-dark /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Greybird-dark none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/Greybird /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/Greybird none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506/share/themes/HighContrast /snap/chromium/1395/data-dir/themes/HighContrast none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create writable mimic over "/snap/chromium/1395": cannot create directory "/tmp/.snap": no such file or directory
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change .....
```

Comment: I had this (or a rather close anyway) error message a few days ago... I hadn't rebooted my machine in 11 days & it forced the update of the *snap* and for me couldn't restart it (in the update it'd ran out of disk space thus the upgrade to the snap had failed to complete). For me I created some space, logged out (or may have rebooted) & it was good again next login/boot (I waited and it re-did the failed upgrade automatically).   **Don't hurry to start snaps on boot (they use login as a trigger to upgrade themselves and often fail to start if attempted during this process); "let them settle"**

Comment: I made the reboot and try to start Chromium. still same problem. Then i run snap remove chromium. It worked! I had to reinstall it loosing all configurations (again). Thank you.